# Setting the Kohana template name dynamically

Tags: php, templates, kohana

I can't seem to set the `$template` variable dynamically of a site built on Kohana.

If I extend the Template_Controller class, I can set the template name like this:

```
public $template = 'template_file_name';
```

But I can't set it dynamically like:

```
public $template = $this->setTemplate();
```

or

```
switch($var):
    default:
       public $template = 'filename';
       break;
endswitch;
```

Changing the `$template` variable using `$this->template` in the constructor breaks the Template_Controller somehow:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object

I need to set the template filename based on a variable set in the constructor, or perhaps pulled from an external library.

Any ideas how to make this possible?

Comment: I don't know anything about Kohana, but does setTemplate() actually return a value? Also you should declare the variable after opening the class (but outside the constructor): `public $template;` and then set it in the constructor: `$this->template = 'template';`.

Comment: Hmm, it should be possible..! What happens when you try? I use to set a lot of properties this way, including ORM relationships. Never tried with temple name though...

Comment: No, setTemplate does not return a value -- I just attempted to return a dynamic value here from an internal function.

Changing the $template variable using $this->template in the constructor breaks the Template_Controller somehow:

Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object

Comment: With the way you're trying to assign the template name to `$template`, `setTemplate()` should return a string. (With `$template = $this->setTemplate()`, you're saying 'Run `setTemplate()` and assign the value that it returns to `$template`). Unless `setTemplate()` updates the value itself (in which case you don't need the assignment), your program definitely wouldn't work as expected. I'm not sure what your `render()` issue is (again, no experience w/ Kohana), but you definitely should *not* be declaring your variables like that (the `switch` statement is particularly disturbing).

Comment: Could you maybe post your entire class definition into something like http://pastebin.com/? I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @Josh - are you asking for the Template_Controller class?  If so, it can be found here: http://dev.kohanaphp.com/projects/kohana2/repository/entry/trunk/system/controllers/template.php

I'm trying to extend this class and dynamically set "$template" (set to "template.php" by default).  The documentation says I can set this in the extended class, but my attempts at setting it *dynamically* all fail.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The class you posted is helpful, but to understand where you're going wrong, I need to understand how it's supposed to be done. I had a quick look at the Kohana site and can't find a useful link to documentation (on the "Documentation") page. It simply says it "can be found at" ... and then nothing. Could you link to the docs you're reading? Also, please post the setTemplate() function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this link may have the answer:

http://stii.co.za/php/overriding-default-template-in-kohana-php/

just run your template constructor as this:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->template = 'foobar';
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Comment: so simple - thanks. (setting template before the parent constructor)

Answer (score 5):

I do it like this:

```
public function action_myaction()
{
    // template
    $this->template = "template/overlay";
    parent::before();

    // display
    $this->template->title = 'My Action';
    $this->template->content = View::factory('myaction')
}
```

More information here:
http://www.workinprogress.ca/kohana32/